# Changing Color of Multiple Forms when the Forms are not loaded

Tags: c#

I tried to change the colour of the form when a checkbox is ticked. The checkbox is on the configuration form, but I cannot change the colour of Form3 which is referenced in the main project.

This is my error. form3 is a type, which is not valid in the given context, the form3 is built as a class.

Form3 Gets loaded when the user clicks on it.

```
private void SetDarkMode(Form form, bool enabled) 
{
  foreach(Control control in form.Controls)
  if (enabled) 
  {
    generalTabPage.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(90, 90, 90);
    ForeColor = SystemColors.Control;
    windowGroupBox.BorderColour = Color.FromArgb(90, 90, 90);

    control.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(90, 90, 90);
    form.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(90, 90, 90);
    applyButton.Enabled = true;
    binDirectoryButton.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(90, 90, 90);
    binDirectoryButton.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat;
    binDirectoryButton.FlatAppearance.BorderColor = Color.WhiteSmoke;
    logDirectoryButton.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(90, 90, 90);
    logDirectoryButton.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat;
    logDirectoryButton.FlatAppearance.BorderColor = Color.WhiteSmoke;
    logDirectoryButton.ForeColor = Color.White;
  } 
  else 
  {
    //Changing this accordily to your System Settings if Windows 10 Dark is enabled or light
    windowGroupBox.BorderColour = SystemColors.Control;
    form.BackColor = SystemColors.Control;
    generalTabPage.BackColor = Color.White;
    ForeColor = Color.Black;
    control.BackColor = Color.White;
    okButton.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(220, 220, 220);
    cancelButton.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(220, 220, 220);
    applyButton.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(220, 220, 220);
    logDirectoryButton.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(220, 220, 220);
    logDirectoryButton.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat;
    logDirectoryButton.FlatAppearance.BorderColor = Color.FromArgb(192, 192, 192);
    logDirectoryButton.ForeColor = Color.Black;
    binDirectoryButton.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(220, 220, 220);
    binDirectoryButton.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat;
    binDirectoryButton.FlatAppearance.BorderColor = Color.FromArgb(192, 192, 192);
    applyButton.Enabled = true;
  }
}

private void DarkModeCheckBox_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
  Form mainForm = Application.OpenForms["MainForm"];
  SetDarkMode(Form4, DarkModeCheckBox.Checked);
  SetDarkMode(this, DarkModeCheckBox.Checked);
  SetDarkMode(mainForm, DarkModeCheckBox.Checked);
  SetDarkMode(Form3, DarkModeCheckBox.Checked);
}
```

I tried changing the colour using settings properties. I can not load the colour properly when it is checked

Comment: Without any punctuation, your question is very hard to read.

Comment: Please provide the code of your `SetDarkMode` function. Other than that, you'd simply go with `FindForm` to get a reference to that Form object. You can than use the `Invoke()` method to change the color.

Comment: Will add it now

Comment: This is not possible.  You'll need to set the BackColor property in the form's constructor or Load event handler.  This gets easy to do when you create a base class for these forms, one that all of them derive from.

Comment: @HansPassant do you have an example, please

Answer (score 0):

Here is the general idea on how to do it:

```
private static void SetBackColor(Color clr, Control c)
{
    if (c.InvokeRequired) {
        c.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate {
            c.BackColor = clr;
        });
    }
    else {
        c.BackColor = clr;
    }

    foreach (Control child in c.Controls) {
        SetBackColor(clr, child);
    }
}
```

You'd call it like this for example:

```
FormCollection targets = Application.OpenForms;
foreach (Form target in targets) {
    SetBackColor(Color.FromArgb(32, 32, 32), target);
}
```

Just change the `SetBackColor` function to your needs. You could check what type of control the passed control is and set the `BackColor` property according to that and so on.

A much more controlled version would be to have a config file in which you specify which control has what color in light mode or dark mode and set the colors within a helper class. Lets say you have a config class like this:

```
public static Color PanelColor(bool darkMode=false) 
{
    if (darkMode) {
        return Color.FromArgb(32, 32, 32);
    }
    return Color.White;
}
```

Than you just say:

```
private void InitializeColorState(bool darkMode=false)  
{
    panel_MyPanel.BackColor = ColorConfig.PanelColor(darkMode);
}
```

You really have a lot of different options here. It is up to you on how to implement it. Again, per function, per config class, per config file and helper class, what ever you prefer...

Comment: The form is not loaded until the user has clicked on it, so basically if the user clicks on the dark mode checkedBox it will set dark mode to all forms

Comment: @JamesClark You cant change a property on an object that is not yet created... You have to create and hide your form, change the properties and show your form. All changes done before the form is properly loaded are practically ignored. Just use the example with the InitializeColorState method and set the dark mode globally. Call the InitializeColorState function in the constructor of your form and you get your dark mode.

Comment: the config file does not load dark mode at all

Comment: @JamesClark As I already said before, if your Form is not loaded and you try to change it before that it won't do a thing. You are missing really basic programming knowledge. This is about instantiating an object, this is programming 101... Read [this](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/C-Sharp-object-instantiation-part-i-constructors/). Since you are still at the fundamentals of programming I wouldn't recommend building a GUI as this requires knowledge about several programming principals like objects, message queues, threading, inheritance and all basic OOP principals